# Is there a jooq dialect for VoltDB

Tags: jooq, voltdb

Is there a dialect for voltdb? This will definitely help in producing dynamic sql for testing perposes.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, as of jOOQ 3.11, there isn't. The pending feature request is: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/1430